# Spark Extent Report - Status filter options for Steps

Tags: extentreports

I'm having trouble viewing the filter icons in the latest Spark extent report version [5.1.1]. These icons are very useful because they allow me to display only the relevant steps when I click on a specific icon. For instance, if I want to see only the failed steps, I can click on the "Failed" icon, as shown in the screenshots from the old version.

Is there any other way to enable this feature in the new report? My report has around 2000 steps, and it's challenging to scroll through all of them to find the failed ones. I would appreciate your help.

Note that I am aware that we can generate a report showing only the failed steps. However, the client needs to see all the steps with the filter options available to view only the failed cases, if any.

Old version

[image]

New version

[image]